# select data by email in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

how can I select email by Id from user collection like this:

```
select emailAddress from users where _id="***"
```

I select it like this in mongo but result is not true

```
db.getCollection('users').find({_id: "QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws"},{ "emails.0.address": 1})
```

**Updated: Sample file**

```
{
  "_id": "QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws",
  "createdAt": ISODate("2017-03-09T06:21:29.664Z"),

  "emails": [{
    "address": "x@gmail.com",
    "verified": true
  }],
  "isDeleted": false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your query, you are expecting to find only first email and only the address field for the given ID. Depending on the expected output, you can try following queries and choose.

---

Will give you all addresses

```
db.users.find({_id:'QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws'}, { "emails.address": 1})
```

Response

```
{
    "_id" : "QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws",
    "emails" : [ 
        {
            "address" : "x@gmail.com"
        }, 
        {
            "address" : "x2@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Will give you only first email address from the array. You have explicitly remove all other fields

```
db.users.find({_id:'QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws'}, 
   { 'emails.verified':0,  _id:0, createdAt: 0, isDeleted: 0, "emails": {$slice: 1}})
```

Response

```
{
    "emails" : [ 
        {
            "address" : "x@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use aggregation to get expected result

```
db.users.aggregate({$match: {_id:'QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws'}}, 
   {$project: {_id:0,email: {$arrayElemAt: ['$emails.address',0]}}})
```

Response
    `{"email" : "x@gmail.com"}`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for your requirement;

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    _id: "QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws"
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$emails"
}, {
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$emails"
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    address: 1
  }
}])
```

This would first match the correct document, then `$unwinds` the `emails` field to expose objects inside, then move the root to it to get focus close to `address` field, then `$project` to only get `address`, which results with your example data (had it contained multiple emails);

```
{ "address": "x@gmail.com" }
{ "address": "xy@gmail.com" }
```